# Apache Django static files not serving DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django

I've a site which is running perfectly in when `DEBUG=True` in settings.py but when I change `DEBUG=False` it stops serving the static files.

From settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_dir"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

From urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

From base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Cerulean theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra command when you deploy your project:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Check [`docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/#deploying-static-files).

Comment: I've already done that